# how to check all parameters of running nodes?

Tags: ros, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm playing with ROS and my Robotino with the robotino stacks.

I launch robotino_node i.e. launch/robotino_node.launch and edit the following line to suit my system:
"param name="hostname" value="192.168.5.5"
changed to
"param name="hostname" value="192.168.1.12"

however, after launch this node i.e. robotino_node... it showed several parameters including "hostname" but I'm dont know how to check its value if it's already set

according to RobotinoNode.cpp, this value is fixed to "192.168.5.5", I don't know if the robotino_node.launch file can re-set this value??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45773/how-to-check-all-parameters-of-running-nodes?/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok.. I got the answer now. It's "rosparam" ... :D I've skipped this tutorial. IT's my mistake

---

Originally posted by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) with karma: 110 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1